# Quick-sort implementation in C

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

Goal: I'm trying to implement quick-sort in C.
Problem: This quick-sort implementation for C goes on an infinite loop. I think the partition function is okay, because using test cases, the pivot (which is set to index 0) always moves to the correct location. I don't understand why the quicksort function would not eventually reach the base case.

What might be the problem with this implementation?

```
# include <stdio.h>

// Swapping algorithm
void swap(int *a, int *b) {
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

// Partitioning algorithm
int partition(int *L, int left, int right){
    int pivot = L[0];

    while (right > left) {
            while (L[left] < pivot) {
                    left = left + 1;
            }
            while (L[right] > pivot) {
                    right = right - 1;
            }
            swap(&L[left], &L[right]);
    }
    swap(&pivot, &L[left]);
    return left;
}

// Quicksort recursion
void quicksort(int *L, int start, int end) {
    if (start >= end) {
            return;
    }
    else {
            int splitPoint = partition(L, start, end);
            quicksort(L, start, splitPoint-1);
            quicksort(L, splitPoint+1, end);
    }
}

int main() {
    int myList[] = {12, 43, -16, 0, 2, 5, 1, 13, 2, 2, -1};
    printf("UNSORTED LIST\n");
    int *pointer = myList;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            printf("%d ", *(pointer+i));
    }
    quicksort(myList, 0, 9);
    printf("\nSORTED LIST\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            printf("%d ", *(pointer+i));
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Your partition code doesn't work correctly.  You should not be looking at `L[0]` when `left > 0`; you should only be looking at elements `L[left]` .. `L[right]`.

Comment: Perhaps you want to use `L[left]` as the pivot, rather than `L[0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial pivot choice should be `L[left]` not `L[0]`, shouldn't it?  However, that's not the only problem in the partition function.

This code works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Swapping algorithm
static inline
void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

static void dump_list(const char *tag, int *ptr, int left, int right)
{
    printf("%15s [%d..%d]: ", tag, left, right);
    for (int i = left; i <= right; i++)
        printf(" %3d", ptr[i]);
    putchar('\n');
}

// Partitioning algorithm
static
int partition(int *L, int left, int right)
{
    int pivot = left;
    int p_val = L[pivot];

    while (left < right)
    {
        while (L[left] <= p_val)
            left++;
        while (L[right] > p_val)
            right--;
        if (left < right)
            swap(&L[left], &L[right]);
    }
    swap(&L[pivot], &L[right]);
    return right;
}

// Quicksort recursion
static
void quicksort(int *L, int start, int end)
{
    if (start >= end)
        return;
    //dump_list("PRE-PARTITION", L, start, end);
    int splitPoint = partition(L, start, end);
    //dump_list("POST-PARTITION", L, start, end);
    //printf("Split point: %d\n", splitPoint);
    quicksort(L, start, splitPoint - 1);
    quicksort(L, splitPoint + 1, end);
}

int main(void)
{
    int myList[] = {12, 43, -16, 0, 2, 5, 1, 13, 2, 2, -1};
    dump_list("UNSORTED LIST", myList, 0, 9);
    quicksort(myList, 0, 9);
    dump_list("SORTED LIST", myList, 0, 9);
}
```

It produces the output:

```
  UNSORTED LIST [0..9]:   12  43 -16   0   2   5   1  13   2   2
    SORTED LIST [0..9]:  -16   0   1   2   2   2   5  12  13  43
```

With the debugging prints enabled, the output is:

```
  UNSORTED LIST [0..9]:   12  43 -16   0   2   5   1  13   2   2
  PRE-PARTITION [0..9]:   12  43 -16   0   2   5   1  13   2   2
 POST-PARTITION [0..9]:    2   2 -16   0   2   5   1  12  13  43
Split point: 7
  PRE-PARTITION [0..6]:    2   2 -16   0   2   5   1
 POST-PARTITION [0..6]:    1   2 -16   0   2   2   5
Split point: 5
  PRE-PARTITION [0..4]:    1   2 -16   0   2
 POST-PARTITION [0..4]:  -16   0   1   2   2
Split point: 2
  PRE-PARTITION [0..1]:  -16   0
 POST-PARTITION [0..1]:  -16   0
Split point: 0
  PRE-PARTITION [3..4]:    2   2
 POST-PARTITION [3..4]:    2   2
Split point: 4
  PRE-PARTITION [8..9]:   13  43
 POST-PARTITION [8..9]:   13  43
Split point: 8
    SORTED LIST [0..9]:  -16   0   1   2   2   2   5  12  13  43
```

Comment: Thank you! The debugging print method is very helpful, too.

Comment: Don't you need a terminating condition for the increment of left inside the nested while loop? If L={6,3,3}, your line    
    while (L[left] <= p_val) left++;
would continue to increment left and leave the higher bound of the array.

Comment: @NikolaPetrovic — interesting question. One answer is "no", but the result isn't correct. I created an array of 9 elements, with the centre three being 6, 3, 3 and the outer elements being clearly different. The code doesn't sort the centre three. `Bounds testing (sorting indexes 3..5):` — `UNSORTED DATA [0..8]:  999 998 997   6   3   3 -997 -998 -999` — `UNSORTED LIST [3..5]:    6   3   3` — `SORTED LIST [3..5]:    6   3   3` — `SORTED DATA [0..8]:  999 998 997   6   3   3 -997 -998 -999`. It's not using the values out of the range; it isn't sorting the values in range.  I'll investigate.

Comment: In your particular case it's not going outside the bounds because you added extra elements - i.e. your L is not {6,3,3}. If you were to use L = {6,3,3} it most certainly would go outside of the bounds. Whether it executes correctly would then only depend on the values in memory after L. Try changing that line to while(L[left] <= p_val && left < right) left++; It should work then.

Comment: I used two versions of the test — the one shown and one with the signs on the 'out of bounds' numbers of opposite signs (changing `+` to `-` and `-` to `+`).  Neither showed signs of using the out of bounds values.  Nevertheless, the result is ***wrong***, and I clearly need to do some surgery on the code.  I will look at your suggestion; thanks.  It will take me at least a few hours to get any update posted — I'm lucky enough to still have a thing called 'a job' and I need to pay some attention to that for a bit, and my dog needs a walk too, even though the temperature is a brisk  -7ºC! Snow!

Comment: I don't see the relevance of personal matters in this. Debugging the code here proves my point https://pastebin.com/0AfGP8BA . It's your code (only the quicksort-related) and left clearly leaves the upper bound of L because there is nothing to prevent it from doing so. Changing the while to while (L[left] <= p_val && left < right) fixed it. Your code is written well regardless.

Comment: As @NikolaPetrovic said, the `while (L[left] <= p_val) left++;` loop is clearly wrong if the entire range contains values lower than or equal to `p_val`, hence my downvote.

Answer (score 1):

I was annoyed that none of the code posted here previously is correct so I wrote a quicksort and proved it correct. It was much harder than I thought. The code below works as far as I can tell and I think my proof of correctness is valid:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int* x, int* y)
{
    int temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}

/**
 * Assuming precondition (P) that `end - begin >= 2`, this function reorders the elements
 * of range [begin, end) and returns a pointer `ret` such that the following
 * postconditions hold:
 *   - (Q1): `ret > begin`
 *   - (Q2): `ret < end`
 * and, for some value `p` in [begin, end):
 *   - (Q3): all values in [begin, ret) are lower than or equal to `p`
 *   - (Q4): all values in [ret, end) are greater than or equal to `p`
 */
int* partition(int* begin, int* end)
{
    // These aliases are unnecessary but make the proof easier to understand.
    int* low  = begin;
    int* high = end;

    int pivot = *(low + (high - low)/2);

    // Loop invariants, all trivially verified at the start of the loop:
    //   - (A): values strictly to the left of `low` are lower than or equal to `pivot`
    //   - (B): there is at least one value at or to the right of `low` that is greater
    //     than or equal to `pivot`
    //   - (C): values at or to the right of `high` are greater than or equal to `pivot`
    //   - (D): there is at least one value strictly to the left of `high` that is lower
    //     than or equal to `pivot`
    //   - (E): `low <= high`
    //
    // The loop terminates because `high - low` decreases strictly at each execution of
    // the body (obvious).
    while (true)
    {
        // This loop terminates because of (B).
        while (*low < pivot)
            ++low;

        // Here, we have
        //   - (1): `*low >= pivot`
        //   - (2): `low <= high` because of (E) and (C)
        //   - properties (A) and (B) still hold because `low` has only moved
        //     past values strictly less than `pivot`

        // This loop terminates because of (D).
        do {
            --high;
        } while (pivot < *high);

        // Here, we have
        //   - (3): `*high <= pivot`
        //   - (4): by (C) which held before this loop, elements strictly to the
        //     right of `high` are known to be greater than or equal to `pivot`
        //     (but now (C) may not hold anymore)

        if (low >= high)
        {
            // Due to (1), (A) and (4), (Q3) and (Q4) are established with `pivot`
            // as `p`.
            // Clearly, (B) proves Q2.
            // See the rest of the answer below for a proof of (Q1).
            // This correctly finishes the partition.
            return low;
        }

        // We have `low < high` and we swap...
        swap(low, high);

        // ...and now,
        //   - by (1) and (4), invariant (C) is re-established
        //   - by (1), invariant (D) is re-established
        //   - (5): by (3), `*low <= pivot`

        ++low;
        // (A) already held before this increment. Thus, because of (5), (A)
        // still holds. Additionally, by (1), after the swap, (B) is
        // re-established. Finally, (E) is obvious.
    }
}

void qsort(int* begin, int* end)
{
    // Trivial base case...
    if (end - begin < 2)
        return;

    // ...therefore pre-condition (P) of `partition` is satisfied.
    int* p = partition(begin, end);

    // Thanks to postconditions (Q1) and (Q2) of `partition`, the ranges
    // [begin, p) and [p, end) are non-empty, therefore the size of the ranges
    // passed to the recursive calls below is strictly lower than the size of
    // [begin, end) in this call. Therefore the base case is eventually reached
    // and the algorithm terminates.

    // Thanks to postconditions (Q3) and (Q4) of `partition`, and by induction
    // on the size of [begin, end), the recursive calls below sort their
    // respective argument ranges and [begin, end) is sorted as a result.
    qsort(begin, p);
    qsort(p, end);
}

int main()
{
    int l[] = { 3, 1, 9, 6, 0, 7, 1, 7, 2, 2, 8 };

    size_t n = sizeof(l)/sizeof(int);

    qsort(l, l + n);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d, ", l[i]);
    }
}
```

To prove (Q1), we must prove that `low` has been incremented at least once before the `return` statement is reached.

If the `return` statement is reached during the first execution of the loop body, then `low >= high` implies that the `--high;` and `++low;` statements in the nested loops must have been executed at least `end - begin` times among them. By precondition (P), `end - begin >= 2`. By (D), the loop decrementing `high` must end with `high >= begin`. Therefore `low` must have been incremented at least once, proving (Q1).

Otherwise, if the return statement is reached during a subsequent execution of the loop body, then the unconditional `++low;` statement proves (Q1).

Comment: Last I remember testing @Jonathan Leffler 's code, it did work with the fix I made a comment about. I appreciate you commenting in rigor behind your implementation.

Comment: @NikolaPetrovic It may indeed be correct but your suggested loop `while(L[left] <= p_val && left < right) ++left;` repeatedly compares `left` and `right` in addition to comparing the two list values, so it is in theory slightly more work than the loops in my version (which is nothing more than a C version of Wikipedia's). Additionally, the `left < right` check of the outer loop in @Joanathan Leffler's code is redundant with the one performed at the end of the loop body. So it's that much less elegant, not that everyone would care about that, of course :)

Comment: I agree.
On the topic of performance though, choosing the pivot as the first, last or even middle element (although it is generally better) isn't particularly great, so that's still something to improve.